# How to Change Value of input field

Tags: html, angular

I want to change the value of this input field. Can someone help please??

```html
<input _ngcontent-c1="" class="margininput ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" id="empcode" name="EmpCode" ngmodel="" placeholder="EmpCode" required="" type="text" ng-reflect-required="" ng-reflect-name="EmpCode" ng-reflect-model="">
```

Comment: Did you copy the above html element from developer tools?

Comment: What is that you want to change?

Comment: edit your question to specific goal so others could not mark your question to negative.

Answer (score 0):

change the input type to whatever you want to change.
example:

```
<input type="number" placeolder="" name="">
 <input type="text" placeolder="" name="">  
 <input type="password" placeolder="" name="">
```

Comment: I got what you want to do others didn't so  that make your question to look like a real question. Best of Luck Bro.